# Проверка зависимостей в Debian

Tags: debian, apt-get

В чем разница между `apt-get -f install` и `apt-get install -f`?

Comment: разница — в порядке указания аргументов.

Answer (score 1):

разница — в порядке указания аргументов.

вторая форма (`apt-get install -f`), конечно, не соответствует [рекомендациям стандарта posix](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_02):

> 12.2 Utility Syntax Guidelines
>   ...
>   Guideline 9:
>       All options should precede operands on the command line.

ну да этому пункту не соответствует огромное количество программ: они отлично принимают опции вперемешку с операндами.

---

например, программа *ls* из операционной системы *gnu* при передаче ей аргументов `xyz` и `-l` ведёт себя точно так же, как если бы аргументы шли в («нормальном») порядке — `-l`, а затем `xyz`:

```
$ ls xyz -l
ls: cannot access 'xyz': No such file or directory
```

хотя «posix-корректно» ей следовало бы написать (подразумевается, что в текущем каталоге нет элементов ф.с. с именами `xyz` или `-l`):

```
ls: cannot access 'xyz': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access '-l': No such file or directory
```

для частного случая упомянутых утилит есть возможность указать им вести себя в соответствии с posix, передав переменную окружения `POSIXLY_CORRECT` (с любым, даже пустым значением):

```
$ POSIXLY_CORRECT= ls xyz -l
ls: cannot access 'xyz': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access '-l': No such file or directory
```

программа же *apt-get*, насколько я вижу, не умеет вести себя подобным образом. поэтому воспринимает два переданных аргумента (`-f` и `install`) как опцию `-f` и операнд `install`, вне зависимости от того, в каком порядке они указаны в команде.