# В каком месте команды правильнее писать -o в Makefile?

Tags: gcc, makefile

На мой взгляд, правильно писать `-o $@` (ну или с конкретным файлом) в конце инструкции, генерирующей каждый файл, т.к. это `-o` чётко разграничивает исходные файлы от выходного. В противном случае выходной файл окажется первым в списке, за которым сразу следуют исходные (правда, между ними можно вставить ещё и опции компилятора). Но в статьях по теме я чаще встречаю обратное написание команд. В чём преимущество, когда в начале команды пишется выходной файл, а потом входные и опции компилятора?

Comment: судя по виду, это опция какой-то программы. вероятно, компилятора. для, например, компилятора *gcc* порядок некоторых опций имеет значение. если правильно припоминаю: `gcc ... -o файл -lбиблиотека ...` — скомпилируется, а `gcc ... -lбиблиотека -o файл ...` — завершится ошибкой (понятно, что библиотека должна быть реально нужна для линковки). // p.s. к программе *make* вопрос отношения не имеет.

Comment: У меня в gcc работало именно так: сначала `-lmylibrary`, потом `-o`. Возможно, дело в старых версиях GCC?

Comment: я не помню точно, что там за чем должно быть. посмотрите в гугле: `gcc порядок линковки`. первый комментарий собственно о том, что вопрос не имеет отношения ни к интерпретатору *make*, ни к файлам, содержащим интерпретируемый им код (так называмемым мэйкфайлам).

Comment: из другого вашего вопроса становится понятнее. вы используете команды вида `программа параметры опции`. что противоречит стандарту posix: опции должны идте раньше параметров. и хотя многие программы «проглатывают» такое нарушение со стороны пользователя, всё-таки лучше и при вводе команд придерживаться требований стандарта.

Comment: А почему имя выходного файла - это опция, а не параметр? И где вообще различие?

Comment: `-o имя` — это опция. см. стандарт: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_02 . конкретно: «Guideline 9:
    All options should precede operands on the command line.»

Comment: фактически дубликат: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/821813/178576